# How to enable SoftScan to read Data Matrix codes in Socket Mobile ScanApi

Tags: ios, objective-c, socketmobile

This is my first question on StackOverflow, so please forgive me if I have not laid out my question correctly!

I am writing an iOS app in Objective-C (Which is derived from the SingleEntry example provided by Socket Mobile on GitHub) using the Scan Api by Socket Mobile, but I am having an issue setting the symbology of the SoftScan feature to read Data Matrix codes. The error returned is -15L, which from the documentation translates to ESKT_NOTSUPPORTED. I am using this from the ScanApi Helper to set the symbology, where deviceInfo is a DeviceInfo object:

```
[ScanApi postSetSymbologyInfo:deviceInfo SymbologyId:kSktScanSymbologyDataMatrix Status:TRUE Target:self Response:@selector(onSetSymbology:)];
```

The onSetSymbology method (this returns the error -15L):

```
-(void)onSetSymbology:(ISktScanObject*)scanObj{
SKTRESULT result=[[scanObj Msg]Result];
if(!SKTSUCCESS(result)){
    // display an error message saying a symbology cannot be set
    NSLog(@"Symbology can not be set, error %ld", result);
}
```

}

I have looked around the documentation and the internet extensively and cannot find any information related to this issue.

So my question is:

- Can Data Matrix codes be scanned/recognised by the SoftScan?
- If so, how do you enable it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find an answer to this? I am having the same problem - other barcodes scan fine

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't yet, but I'm in the same position with every barcode scanning except Data Matrix barcodes. If I do find a solution I'll be sure to post it here.

Comment: @Cechner Socket Mobile have now added support for Data Matrix barcodes :)

Comment: this is great news, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exchanging some emails with the developers at Socket Mobile, they have kindly added support for Data Matrix barcodes in the latest version of their Scan API SDK (10.3.83).